# What is means by Plotting an Image ?What is the purpose of Image plotting in 2D or 3D?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

What is means by Plotting an Image ?

What is the purpose of Image plotting in 2D or 3D ?

Comment: [It's all here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-high-level-plotting-functions.html)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @ColinTBowers I have an 2D Image and now i want to plot it..how to do it

Comment: how about posting some code and explaining your problem in more detail? what *2D Image* do you want to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't plot an image, you plot data, either in the plain form, or resulting from equations, for images, you just display them, using functions like [image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) 
Of course, images are in there raw form are data too, but they have special formats.